# "Error during linking" for a Java compiler written in Ocaml

Tags: java, compiler-construction, ocaml

I have found a [source](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~stevez/stse-work/javac/index.html) of Java compiler written in Ocaml which should work.

But when I do `make`, it finished with an error:

```
unzip.o: In function `camlUnzip__59':
(.data+0x540): undefined reference to `camlzip_deflateEnd'
unzip.o: In function `camlUnzip__59':
(.data+0x544): undefined reference to `camlzip_deflate'
unzip.o: In function `camlUnzip__59':
(.data+0x548): undefined reference to `camlzip_deflateInit'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
File "caml_startup", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: Error during linking
make: *** [javacx] Error 2
```

It is odd that the file "caml_startup" even does not exist in the folder. Could anyone help? Thank you very much.

Comment: Why don't you contact the authors?

Comment: I would like first to make sure if it is straightforward, I could not say because i am not an expert of Ocaml or compiler...

Answer (score 4):

`caml_startup` is part of the OCaml runtime.

The project's website mentions that it works with OCaml 3.09, which is quite old.  It worked for me with 3.10 (which is still quite old; latest release is 3.12) - maybe it just doesn't work with more recent versions.

However, as a first guess, I would try simply deleting these definitions from `unzip.ml` - they are never called, and declare external routines which are not actually implemented (whereas other `external` routines in `unzip.ml` are implemented in `zlib.c`):

```
external deflate_init: int -> bool -> stream = "camlzip_deflateInit"
external deflate:
  stream -> string -> int -> int -> string -> int -> int -> flush_command
         -> bool * int * int
  = "camlzip_deflate_bytecode" "camlzip_deflate"
external deflate_end: stream -> unit = "camlzip_deflateEnd"
```

Comment: Indeed, `deflate` and friends are declared but neither defined nor used. This was ok up to 3.10 (the linker never looked for them because they were unused) but 3.11 insists on linking them, I think because they might be used by a dynamically loaded module. Just removing the declarations is enough to build `javajx` with 3.11.